# Why do ssh operations always ask for passphrase? (with ed25519)

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I just updated my ssh key and added a passphrase,
however it constantly nags me for it now,
such as when I do a git (or mercurial hg) push.  `ssh-agent` is running:

```
xxx  1303  1118  0 09:16 ?  00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent
   /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session 
   /usr/bin/im-launch mate-session
```

I tried `ssh-add`:

```
> ssh-add
Identity added: /home/…/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/…/.ssh/id_rsa)
Enter passphrase for /home/…/.ssh/id_ed25519: 
Could not add identity "/home/…/.ssh/id_ed25519": 
    communication with agent failed
```

What is missing?  16.04 Ubuntu Mate, in case it matters.

Comment: `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` -- are you sure you are connected to this `ssh-agent` and not the GNOME one, that might not support ED25519 keys?

Comment: `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`  - no idea?

Answer (score 8):

### Edit 2018:

This was resolved in gnome-keyring by [wrapping ssh-agent](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775981) recently so the workarounds should not be needed anymore and everything should work out of the box.

### Original workarounds for older systems:

`/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh` is path of Gnome keyring (seahorse), which does not support Ed25519 keys. There are two possibilities:

1. Do not use ED25519 keys and use RSA (which should be good enough)
2. Run real `ssh-agent` in your startup scripts (`~/.xsession`) using

   ```
    eval `ssh-agent`
   ```

Comment: Interesting that seahorse does not support this. Is there an issue for this?

Comment: There is a bug about this in GNOME bugzilla for almost three years: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723274

Comment: .xsession didn't seem to work, looks like gnome-keyring clobbers ssh-agent: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775189

Comment: For testing purpose you should be able to start the agent manually/in `~/.bashrc`. It just overwrites the environment variable set by gnome-keyring. Similar way should be possible in some of the X startup scripts (not too familiar in these waters). Though implementing ed22519 should not be too hard since it is already available in libgcrypt. If I will have time, I will have a look into that.

Comment: This was resolved in gnome-keyring by wrapping ssh-agent recently.